# Open Activity from shared project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Is it possible to start Activity in Android project by clicking button created in shared project?

I managed to call the function in Android project from **shared project** by using dependency like this:

```
btn.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{
    DependencyService.Get<IBtnAction>().DoSomething();
};
```

And in **Android project** I did (and get the exception):

```
public class BtnAction_Android : Activity, IBtnAction
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse("content://com.android.calendar/time/"));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You have opened an activity from a shared project. `Java.Lang.NullPointerException` means one of your arguments you are passing is `null`... my guess here would be `intent = null`

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the case - intent is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, I forgot this line

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

This was null.